# Python 3.9.4 how to find text within a large string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, web-scraping, python-3.9

I am using a scraper to get my daily lunch menu (school) for a discord bot.  One problem I have is that the menu i am getting is for all week.  How can i locate the specific date, then the specific meal (json printed as a string in python)

Ex:

```
"days":[
   {
  "date": "05-02"
     "meal": "pasta"
   }
   {
  "date": "05-03"
      "meal": "Burger"
```

How does one efficiently and simply locate the `"meal"` for each day (without searching for just "meal" within the document) Also sorry i'm not sending the file, I don't want to dox myself :/

Comment: What code do you already have?  This is JSON, so once you JSON decode it, it's just a matter of iterating through the members of obj['days'] until you find tomorrow date.

Comment: Load the json into a pandas dataframe dataframe. Convert Date column into datetime and then loc to find the dates greater than today or equal to as required and you have every value associated with that date.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to give you an answer based on the information you provided.

As you said you have your data as a stringified json. First start with decoding it. You can do it with the `json` builtin package) :

```
    import json

    json_as_str = '{"days": [{"date": "05-02", "meal": "Pasta"}, {"date": "05-03", "meal": "Burger"}, {"date": "05-04", "meal": "Pizza"}]}'

    json_as_dict = json.loads(json_as_str)
```

Once you have your data as an iterable object (i.e a dict), get today's date for filtering (from the `datetime` builtin package) and get the corresponding string in the format of your data (as you provided them) :

```
    from datetime import date

    today = date.today()
    today_as_formatted_str = f"{today:%m-%d}"
```

If you want any other day, you can get it with the `timedelta` object from the `datetime` package :

```
    from datetime import timedelta

    yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)  # Also today + timedelta(days=-1)
    tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=1)
    day_after_tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=2)
    ...
```

You can now filter the `days` list of your json object, based on the `date` key of each of the list's elements :

```
    def filter_records_on_date(record):
        return record["date"] == today_as_formatted_str

    # Extract all the elements of the list that correspond to today's date
    today_records = filter(
        filter_records_on_date,
        json_as_dict["days"],
    )
```

You can achieve the same thing with :

```
    today_records = filter(
        lambda record: record["date"] == today_as_formatted_str,
        json_as_dict["days"],
    )
```

Now that you have the list of all meal records for today's date, just extract the corresponding meal :

```
    def extract_meal_from_record(record):
        return record["meal"]

    today_meals = list(map(extract_meal_from_record, today_records))
```

Once again you can achieve the same result with :

```
    today_meals = list(map(lambda record: record["meal"], today_records))
```

If you are sure there is only one record per day, you can extract the only meal with :

```
    today_meal = today_meals[0]
```

This is a simple yet efficient solution based on the few information you provided on your data structure.